# Calculate shipping based on square meters (m2)

Tags: ubercart

I have lengths of material as products in Ubercart, 3 and I need to be able to calculate shipping of them based on their length x width. Plenty of options for shipping based on weight but that's not what is needed here. I've got width and lengths fields in my product type already plus I have created one called "m2" to enter the square meters manually in case that is easier. Just a bit stuck as to what I should do next. Could rules help me? Maybe modifying the flat rate module or would a custom module be needed?

Comment: Still hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with a a similar problem.

From what I can see, the only way to do it with Ubercart is to connect to the API of an appropriate shipping company that supports volumetric shipping calculations. The availability of this (in terms of an existing module) will depend on which country you're working in, plus it will depend on whether there is an existing module that supports the specific carrier you've chosen.

The US is obviously well-served in this regard. Outside the US, support can be patchy, to say the least.